# div height is 0 when position is absolute

Tags: javascript, html, css

**I don't know why Line 2 above Line 1**

I want to add Line line 2 after Line 1. I don't want to remove position absolute because this is related to some different webpage.

[Codepen Link of that Web page](https://codepen.io/nitishk72/pen/qYVKre)

```js
 console.log('a', document.getElementById('a').getBoundingClientRect().height);
 console.log('b', document.getElementById('b').getBoundingClientRect().height);
 console.log('c', document.getElementById('c').getBoundingClientRect().height);
```

```css
#a{
  position:realative;
  background:#ef0000;
}
#b{
  position:absolute;
}
#c{
  
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div id="b">
    <h2>Line 1 :</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="c">
    <h2>Line 2 :</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: absolute takes the element out of the normal "flow" - it's height, by the way, is NOT 0 ... add `console.log(document.getElementById('b').getBoundingClientRect())` and you'll see it's height is definitely > 0

Comment: help me.
Yes, its height is not zero. It was zero in case of my webpage.

Comment: @JaromandaX Check this 
console.log(document.getElementById('a').getBoundingClientRect());
your will get height 0. I was talking about this. may be my question was not clear.

Comment: No, both `a` and `b` have a height (what browser are you using?)

Comment: Is there is any code which can help me?

Comment: help you how? You say something has a height of zero - but you've yet to show what? I've edited your code to log the height of a, b and c - none of them are zero

Comment: If you will see the height of a, b, c then you will find that height of a is equals to c. It means when you will remove c from a, height of a will automaticallly become 0.

Comment: I want Line 2 after Line 1.
once see the output.
I don't have any issue with height , I only want Line 2 after Line 1

Comment: did you read any of my comments regarding absolutely positioned elements? they do not effect the dimensions of the containing folder, nor do they effect the position of subsequent elements - perhaps you want `position:relative` - if you want line 2 after line 1, then don't position it absolute!!!!

Comment: yes sir, I read but I want to bring absolute element to noraml flow . If it is possible

Comment: absolute removes the element from the normal flow, so it will not affect the height of its parent. That's why a and c both have height 27. Maybe `position: absolute` is the wrong solution for your problem.

Comment: @nitishk72, absolute position takes it out of flow - that's its purpose! So if you don't want it removed from flow, don't position absolute!

Comment: you say you don't have an issue with height - but you incorrectly claim in the title of the question that the height of the div is 0 when it is absolutely positioned - clearly it is not zero

Comment: No sir that not like that. If there will the height of div.a = div.b + div.c then my problem will automatically solve. To tell you my exact problem I told that I only want Line 2 after Line 1 and I don't problem with heihgt 0

Comment: Check this : https://codepen.io/nitishk72/pen/qYVKre
here is my exact issue

Answer (score 0):

```
     <div id="a">
          <div id="b">
            <h2>Line 1 :</h2>
            <div id="c">
            <h2>Line 2 :</h2>
          </div>
          </div>

        </div>

    place div c inside b.

    Make id  'b' as ancestor to 'c'.so,since 'b'  is positioned absolute its child will be  positioned relative to 'b'. 

LINE1
LINE2
```

Comment: Thanks, man but I not looking for this. I don't want this one. I don't want to modify my HTML. I want to do this using CSS if possible.
https://codepen.io/nitishk72/pen/qYVKre
See here your solution will not work and I want solution for this

Answer (score 0):

Here it is.. You can remove `position: absolute` and can use `display` like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vzwstn4j/)

```js
var current ;
(function(){
  const cTab = document.getElementById('tab-control').children;
  current = cTab[0].dataset.tab;
  for(var i =0;i<=cTab.length;i++){
    cTab[i].addEventListener('click',changeTab);
  }
})();
function changeTab(){
  var clickTab  = this.dataset.tab;
  document.querySelector('[data-tab='+current+']').classList.remove('active');
  document.querySelector('[data-tab='+clickTab+']').classList.add('active');
  var tab = document.getElementById(clickTab);
  document.getElementById(current).classList.remove('active');
  tab.classList.add('active');
  current =  clickTab;
}
```

```css
body{
  background:#efefef;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:1.2em;
}
#tab{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width:80%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
#tab ul#tab-control{
  border-bottom:1px solid #444;
  padding:0;
}
#tab #tab-control li{
  display:inline-flex;
  padding:10px 15px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
#tab #tab-control li.active{
  border:1px solid #444;
  border-bottom:0;
  border-top-left-radius:4px;
  border-top-right-radius:4px;
  position:relative;
}

#tab #tab-control li.active:after{
  position:absolute;
  content:'';
  bottom:-2px;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:2px;
  background:#efefef;
}
#tab #tab-content{
  position:relative;
}

#tab #tab-content > *{
/*   display:none; */
  opacity:0;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in; 
  display: none;
}
#tab #tab-content > .active {
  display: block;
}
#tab #tab-content .active{
/*   display:block; */
  opacity:1;
  z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="tab">
    <ul id="tab-control">
      <li data-tab="tab-1" class="active">Home</li>
      <li data-tab="tab-2">About</li>
      <li data-tab="tab-3">Contact</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab-content">
      <div id="tab-1" class="active">
        <h1>Tab 1</h1>
        <p>
          Raw denim you probably haven't heard of them jean shorts Austin. Nesciunt tofu stumptown aliqua, retro synth master cleanse. Mustache cliche tempor, williamsburg carles vegan helvetica. Reprehenderit butcher retro keffiyeh dreamcatcher synth. Cosby sweater eu banh mi, qui irure terry richardson ex squid. Aliquip placeat salvia cillum iphone. Seitan aliquip quis cardigan american apparel, butcher voluptate nisi qui.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="tab-2">
        <h1>Tab 2</h1>
        <p>
          Food truck fixie locavore, accusamus mcsweeney's marfa nulla single-origin coffee squid. Exercitation +1 labore velit, blog sartorial PBR leggings next level wes anderson artisan four loko farm-to-table craft beer twee. Qui photo booth letterpress, commodo enim craft beer mlkshk aliquip jean shorts ullamco ad vinyl cillum PBR. Homo nostrud organic, assumenda labore aesthetic magna delectus mollit. Keytar helvetica VHS salvia yr, vero magna velit sapiente labore stumptown. Vegan fanny pack odio cillum wes anderson 8-bit, sustainable jean shorts beard ut DIY ethical culpa terry richardson biodiesel. Art party scenester stumptown, tumblr butcher vero sint qui sapiente accusamus tattooed echo park.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="tab-3">
        <h1>Tab 3</h1>
        <p>
          Etsy mixtape wayfarers, ethical wes anderson tofu before they sold out mcsweeney's organic lomo retro fanny pack lo-fi farm-to-table readymade. Messenger bag gentrify pitchfork tattooed craft beer, iphone skateboard locavore carles etsy salvia banksy hoodie helvetica. DIY synth PBR banksy irony. Leggings gentrify squid 8-bit cred pitchfork. Williamsburg banh mi whatever gluten-free, carles pitchfork biodiesel fixie etsy retro mlkshk vice blog. Scenester cred you probably haven't heard of them, vinyl craft beer blog stumptown. Pitchfork sustainable tofu synth chambray yr.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>
      Something after Tab
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is animation in my code which will is not working in your case.

Comment: by the way preiously my code was exactly like your and after some time I added animation to it

Comment: Then better to use jQuery. Or you can't use

Comment: If jQuery can do then JS can also do.

Comment: i meant, you can get height of tallest element and set height on tab container.